# Pygame calculations not correct for manipulating pygame.time.get_ticks() into a timer

Tags: python, function, time, while-loop, pygame

I am currently using pygame for a NEAT self-driving car simulation. The code below is in a while loop, inside a `run()` function. Every time each generation ends, the while loop also is broken but restarted again. Each generation ends at 120 seconds, so I made the timer below to view how much time passed, and it works correctly for the first generation, but for each generation, after that, the output is messed up. i.e. gen 2 starts at 80, ends at 120, but the seconds are longer than usual, etc...

*Edit*: The window isn't freezing, everything works, including `pygame.time.get_ticks()`, but when I try to use it to display the time and manipulate it using calculations to reset to 0 every 120 seconds, the calculations aren't correct because the time just gets distorted. Also, I checked out the post I was directed to when my previous question was closed, that didn't fix my problem.

Code:

```
import pygame

generation = 0
screen_width = 1500
screen_height = 800
generations = [1, 2, 3]

def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    tick = 60
    global generation
    generation +=1
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Aharoni', 20)
    while 1:
        pygame.event.pump()

        for event in pygame.event.get():  # Loop to check if anything that can be pressed was pressed:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If the quit button was pressed:
                sys.exit(0)  # Exit the program.

        if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= 120000 * generation:  # if the ticks that passed is greater than 120k (120.s)*gen:
            break  # Exit the while loop and end the generation.

           # Draw a transparent box for stats to be written on.
        stat_box = pygame.Surface((200, 200))  # Create a surface with (200, 200) resolution.
        stat_box.set_alpha(50)  # Make the surface '50' transparent.
        stat_box.fill((255, 255, 255))  # Set the color of the surface to (255, 255, 255) / black.
        screen.blit(stat_box, (screen_width / 150, screen_height / 1.355932))  # Render box to the screen.


        gen_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()  # Set the variable to be the same amount of ticks, divide it by 1k to get
        gen_time = gen_time / 1000          # seconds, and divide it by the generation amount to create a timer.
        gen_time = gen_time / generation
        gen_time = str(gen_time)  # Convert the variable to a string from being a number.

        text = font.render("Generation clock: " + gen_time[0:3] + "s", True, (0, 0, 0))  # Text to be drawn, and color.
        text_rect = text.get_rect()  # Grab the rectangle borders for the text.
        text_rect.center = (110, 620)  # Coordinates for text to be drawn at.
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)  # Render 'text' to the screen at the position of 'text_rect'.

        pygame.display.flip()  # Refresh the entire screen (graphically).
        clock.tick_busy_loop(tick)  # Tick the clock by 'ticks' amount.

for i in generations:
    run()
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not call pygame.event.pump(), ill try to add some more code to make it reproducible, ill just need a few minutes.

Comment: Sorry, I beg you pardon but, I did try calling that, and removed it because it didn't fix my problem(didn't affect the program in a good or bad way), I'm not entirely sure but I don't think the time has anything to do with events? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've updated the code so my issue is now reproducible. Sorry if I came off rude, and thanks again! (I included the line you said to include to show it doesn't fix it. edit: my program has also never locked up before, and ive ran it for days, so i removed the line as i think it may be useless in my case)

Comment: Oh, I believe that's a mistake from when I was copying and pasting my code, it should only be in the function, although, the function is also called multiple times so should I call those outside of the function also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks):

> [...] Return the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called

See [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init):

> [...] It is safe to call this `init()` more than once as repeated calls will have no effect.

Therefore you need to call [`pygame.qiut()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) at the end of a generation.

```py
def run():
    pygame.init()

    # [...]

    while 1:
        # [...]

    pygame.quit() # <---
```

---

Alternatively, you can get the start time before the loop and calculate the time difference in the loop:

```py
def run():
    pygame.init()

    # [...]

    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    while 1:
        # [...]

        elapsed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time
        if elapsed_time >= 120000 * generation:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you! That works correctly (although I put the quit statement at the end of the run function), but it also closes out the window at the end of each generation, which isn't ideal, so I was wondering if it's possible to reset pygame.time.get_ticks(),  if not, then thanks anyways, I can finally rid my program of bugs!

Comment: @EshanT201 No it is not possible to "reset" `pygame.time.get_ticks()` as clearly stated in the docs. However, you can find an alternative solution in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I prefer the second one, have a great day!